Use of maps in quantum coding schemes
Suppose we construct a quantum coding scheme in which Alice and Bob agree on a number of things in advance, including, say, a bijection $\gamma$ between two sets of vectors (which live in different Hilbert spaces) which Bob has to apply once he receives a message/state from Alice. Is it inherent to quantum information theory that $\gamma$ needs to be linear (or even unitary), or doesn't such an "agreement map" need to be constrained ?
